# Autodesk Forge Viewer call Built-in Extension function

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

I'm trying to call an extension in Forge Viewer v7 that has the "Measure" Tool and use it to make a measurement between 2 objects. How can I call an extension, and what extension has the "Measure" tool that I need to call?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The measure tool is implemented by the `Autodesk.Measure` extension which is loaded automatically by the viewer:

```js
const measureExt = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Measure');
```

The tool can be retrieved from the viewer's tool controller:

```js
const measureTool = viewer.toolController.getTool('measure');
```

The tool itself provides some methods you could theoretically use to create measurements programmatically (e.g., `measureTool.setMeasurements(measurements)`) but unfortunately that would require some trial&error as this is not an officially supported feature. You could try exploring the [measure extension script](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/Measure/Measure.js) to reverse-engineer the structure of the `measurements` parameter that's being passed into the `setMeasurements` method, and then call the method with your own input.